# Issue reading data with ipumsr using PUMAs

Tags: r

I'm trying to read some data from ipums USA and it's worked before, but I'm suddenly getting the error "Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : factor level [2] is duplicated" Earlier, when just trying to display the PUMA data, I also got "Error: 'labels' must be unique" on a different computer. I'll put the code I was using below, but I've been using this data with PUMA and it hasn't happened before. Can anyone tell me what this means or what changed?

```
ddi <- read_ipums_ddi("usa_00021.xml")
data <- read_ipums_micro(ddi)
data[13] #13 is the IND column and this produces the error
data$IND #this does not produce an error
```

this gets the "Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : factor level [2] is duplicated" error on my current computer

```
ddi <- read_ipums_ddi("usa_00021.xml")
data <- read_ipums_micro(ddi)
data[8] #this is the PUMA column
```

this gets the 'Error: 'labels' must be unique' error on the other computer. This computer has the same issue listed above, but also gives me this. This is also the computer I had been using with no previous issue

(Sorry if anything is formated wrong--first question)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to an error in the print formatting introduced by recent versions of ipumsr and haven.

It has been fixed as a [pull request into haven](http://github.com/tidyverse/haven/pull/425), so if you're able to install C++ packages from github, you can run the following command:

```r
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/haven", pull = 425)
```

If that's not an option, you can disable the printing behavior by doing the following:

```r
options(haven.show_pillar_labels = FALSE)
options(ipumsr.show_pillar_labels = FALSE)
```

### Edit:

Just to confirm - this is how the options work on my computer - I'm curious why this wouldn't work on yours. If you have time, can you see if this code works for you?

```r
library(ipumsr)
x <- tibble::tibble(x = haven::labelled(c(1, 2, 3), c(x = 1, x = 2)))

x
#> Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)): factor level [2] is duplicated

options(haven.show_pillar_labels = FALSE)
options(ipumsr.show_pillar_labels = FALSE)

x
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>           x
#>   <dbl+lbl>
#> 1         1
#> 2         2
#> 3         3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: For whatever reason, neither of these options seemed to work for me. However, I don't need the labels so I ended up using zap_labels() and now I'm able to use the data

Comment: Bummer, sorry about that. If you have time, can you try running the code in my update? If it doesn't work, can you send the versions of ipumsr and haven you have? I'd like to be able to support people who hit this going forward. Thanks!